# Selenium Testing Safari Extension

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver, safari-extension

When you attempt to run Selenium tests in a scripting context whose origin is at "safari-extension://...", the session hangs. I believe the problem is caused by extension sandboxing, which means if I get Selenium running in the same origin as the extension I am testing, it should be possible to execute selenium commands in my extension.

Question: Can I incorporate [the Safari Driver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/#git%2Fjavascript%2Fsafari-driver%2Fextension) into my Safari extension during testing to circumvent sandboxing?

Answer (score 0):

We modified the Safari driver to navigate `extension://` pages, and the problem persists. It looks like Apple blocks Selenium at the extension level :(